# Forcing a QiChatbot to reply to a phrase typed by the user

Tags: android, chatbot, future, pepper

I am working on a Pepper application on android that uses a QiChatbot to communicate with users about minerals. I want to make the chatbot also available for on-screen use for people with hearing and/or speech impairment. So i am building a UI like facebook messenger. While I am able to get the reply from pepper and show it on the screen, I cannot find a way to force a String that I am getting from an EditText by the user to the chatbot.

I have tried using:

`Future<ReplyReaction> replyToFuture = chatbot.async().replyTo(userPhrase, localeEN);`

and

`Future<Void> acknowledgeHeardFuture = chatbot.async().acknowledgeHeard(userPhrase,localeEN);`

with no success

Below you can see the whole chat and chatbot setup:

```
private QiChatbot buildQiChatbot() {
        Topic lexicon = TopicBuilder
                .with(qiContext)
                .withResource(R.raw.lexicon)
                .build();
        Topic topic_minerals = TopicBuilder
                .with(qiContext)
                .withResource(R.raw.topic_minerals)
                .build();
        Topic test = TopicBuilder
                .with(qiContext)
                .withResource(R.raw.test_topic)
                .build();


        List<Topic> topicList = new LinkedList<Topic>();
        topicList.add(test);
        //topicList.add(lexicon);
        //topicList.add(topic_minerals);

        chatbot = QiChatbotBuilder
                .with(qiContext)
                .withTopics(topicList)
                .withLocale(localeEN)
                .build();

        chatbot.addOnBookmarkReachedListener(bookmark -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "Bookmark " + bookmark.getName() + " reached.");

        });

        chatbot.addOnEndedListener(endReason -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "Chatbot ended for reason: " + endReason);
            chatFuture.requestCancellation();
        });

        return chatbot;
    }

    private Chat buildChat(QiChatbot chatbot) {
        chat = ChatBuilder
                .with(qiContext)
                .withChatbot(chatbot)
                .build();

        chat.addOnStartedListener(() -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "[CHAT] Chat started.");

        });
        chat.addOnListeningChangedListener(listening -> {
            if (listening) {
                Log.i(TAG, "[CHAT] Listening START.");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "[CHAT] Listening END.");
            }

        });
        chat.addOnHeardListener(heardPhrase -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "[CHAT] Heard phrase: " + heardPhrase.getText());

        });
        chat.addOnNormalReplyFoundForListener(input -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "[CHAT] Reply found for user message: " + input.getText());
        });
        chat.addOnNoPhraseRecognizedListener(() -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "[CHAT] No phrase recognized.");
        });
        chat.addOnSayingChangedListener(sayingPhrase -> {
            if (!sayingPhrase.getText().isEmpty()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "[CHAT] Pepper Reply: " + sayingPhrase.getText());
                messageItemList.add(new MessageItem(LayoutRobot, R.drawable.icons8_user_100, sayingPhrase.getText()));
                messageAdapter.notifyItemInserted(messageItemList.size());
            }
        });
        chat.addOnFallbackReplyFoundForListener(input -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "[CHAT] Fallback Reply found for user message: " + input.getText());
        });
        chat.addOnNoReplyFoundForListener(input -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "[CHAT] NO Reply found for user message: " + input.getText());
        });
        return chat;
    }
```

### **Edit 1:**

I tried to use replyTo the way [@Victor Paléologue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3836562/victor-pal%C3%A9ologue) mentioned:

```
Future<ReplyReaction> replyFuture = chatbot.async().replyTo(userPhrase, localeEN);
                replyFuture.thenConsume(future -> {
                    if (future.hasError()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Reply Future [ERROR]: " + future.getErrorMessage());
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Reply Future [SUCCESS]: ");
                        ReplyReaction replyReaction = future.get();
                        ChatbotReaction chatbotReaction = replyReaction.getChatbotReaction();
                        chatbotReaction.runWith(speechEngine);
                    }
                });
```

This code produces no errors. If the `userPhrase`  is not present in the `Topic` that the chatbot runs, the error gets captured at the first `if` clause.

If the chatbot knows the phrase the following code seems to run but I am not getting any feedback. For some reason the chatbot doesn't actually get the phrase because if it was I would see the logs from the following method.

```
chatbot.addOnBookmarkReachedListener(bookmark -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "Bookmark " + bookmark.getName() + " reached.");

        });
```

### **Edit 2:**

Upon further inspection I chained all the operations one after the other to see how the futures are completed:

```
Future<ReplyReaction> replyFuture = chatbot.async().replyTo(userPhrase, localeEN);
                replyFuture.thenConsume(future -> {
                    if (future.hasError()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Reply Reaction Future [ERROR]: " + future.getErrorMessage());
                    } else if(future.isCancelled()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Reply Reaction Future [CANCELED]: ");
                    } else if(future.isDone()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Reply Reaction Future [DONE]: ");
                        func1(future);
                    } else if(future.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Reply Reaction Future [SUCCESS]: ");
                        func1(future);
                    }
                });
```

```
private void func1(Future<ReplyReaction> replyReactionFuture) throws ExecutionException {
        ReplyReaction replyReaction = replyReactionFuture.get();
        Future<ChatbotReaction> chatbotReactionFuture = replyReaction.async().getChatbotReaction();
        chatbotReactionFuture.thenConsume(future -> {
            if (future.hasError()){
                Log.e(TAG, "Chatbot Reaction Future [ERROR]: " + future.getErrorMessage());
            } else if(future.isCancelled()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Chatbot Reaction Future [CANCELED]: ");
            } else if(future.isDone()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Chatbot Reaction Future [DONE]: ");
                func2(future);
            } else if(future.isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Chatbot Reaction Future [SUCCESS]: ");
                func2(future);
            }
        });
    }

private void func2(Future<ChatbotReaction> chatbotReactionFuture) throws ExecutionException {
        ChatbotReaction chatbotReaction = chatbotReactionFuture.get();
        Future<Void> runWithFuture = chatbotReaction.async().runWith(speechEngine);
        runWithFuture.thenConsume(future -> {
            if (future.hasError()){
                Log.e(TAG, "runWith Future [ERROR]: " + future.getErrorMessage());
            } else if(future.isDone()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "runWith Future [DONE]: ");
            } else if(future.isCancelled()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "runWith Future [CANCELED]: ");
            } else if(future.isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "runWith Future [SUCCESS]: ");
            }
        });
    }
```

The `Log` output is the following:

```
2023-11-17 21:34:56.035 10000-10031/? I/Main Activity: Reply Reaction Future [DONE]: 
2023-11-17 21:34:56.044 10000-10030/? I/Main Activity: Chatbot Reaction Future [DONE]: 
2023-11-17 21:34:56.068 10000-10031/? I/Main Activity: runWith Future [DONE]:
```

Which means that all the futures are completed by nothing inside the chatbot gets triggered.

### **Edit 3: (SOLUTION FOUND) **

I canceled the chat before running `replyTo` and all the subsequent code and it works. Then I start the chat again after the `runWithFuture` is done.

This is the complete code that runs in the `onCLick` method.

```java
chatFuture.requestCancellation();
Future<ReplyReaction> replyToFuture = chatbot.async().replyTo(userPhrase, localeEN);
    replyToFuture.thenConsume(replyReactionFuture -> {
        if (replyReactionFuture.hasError()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Reply Reaction Future [ERROR]: " + replyReactionFuture.getErrorMessage());
        } else {
            ReplyReaction replyReaction = replyReactionFuture.get();
            Future<ChatbotReaction> getChatbotReactionFuture = replyReaction.async().getChatbotReaction();
            getChatbotReactionFuture.thenConsume(chatbotReactionFuture -> {
            if (chatbotReactionFuture.hasError()){
                Log.e(TAG, "Chatbot Reaction Future [ERROR]: " + chatbotReactionFuture.getErrorMessage());
            } else {
                ChatbotReaction chatbotReaction = chatbotReactionFuture.get();
                Future<Void> runWithFuture = chatbotReaction.async().runWith(speechEngine);
                runWithFuture.thenConsume(future -> {
                    if (future.hasError()){
                        Log.e(TAG, "runWith Future [ERROR]: " + future.getErrorMessage());
                    } else {
                        chat = buildChat(chatbot);
                        chatFuture = chat.async().run();
                        chatFuture.thenConsume(future1 -> {
                            if (future1.hasError()) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Chat finished with error: " + future1.getErrorMessage());
                            } else {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Chat finished: " + future1.get().toString());
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Also in order to get the `chatbot` reply when the `chat` is not running I had to add a listener after making the `SpeechEngine`

```
speechEngine = conversation.makeSpeechEngine(robotContext);
speechEngine.addOnSayingChangedListener(phrase -> {
    String sayingText = phrase.getText();
    if (!sayingText.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "[SPEECH ENGINE] Pepper Reply: " + sayingText);
        messageItemList.add(new MessageItem(LayoutRobot, R.drawable.ic_pepper_w, sayingText));
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            messageAdapter.notifyItemInserted(messageAdapter
            .getItemCount() - 1);
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messageItemList.size() - 1);
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: What failed when you called `chatbot.replyTo`?

Comment: If the user input is present in the topic file it doesn't fail. Its just that nothing happens when I expect it to reach a bookmark for example.

Comment: Is the chat running while you do that?
It's not impossible it conflicts with using the `speechEngine` directly.

Comment: Yes. The chat is running while this happens. If I type a message at the `Dialog View` of the emulator the chat replies correctly.

Comment: So, does it work when you stop the chat temporarily?

Comment: @VictorPaléologue I just tried it and it works!!! I will show the final solution on a question edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chatbot.replyTo` returns a reply object. It has a `chatbotReaction` that you can `runWith(SpeechEngine engine)`. [The speech engine is given by the `Conversation` service](https://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/doc/javadoc/qisdk/com.aldebaran.qi.sdk.object.conversation/-conversation/make-speech-engine.html).

How to use it is tricky and not well documented.
In theory this is meant to work:

```java
RobotContext robotContext = qiContext.getRobotContext();
Conversation conversation = qiContext.getConversation();
SpeechEngine speechEngine = conversation.makeSpeechEngine(robotContext);

ReplyReaction replyReaction = chatbot.replyTo(userPhrase, localeEN);
ChatbotReaction reaction = replyReaction.getChatbotReaction();
reaction.runWith(speechEngine);
```

Note that you may need to stop the chat before running the reaction with the `speechEngine`.